# Multiple external signature for same PDF using pdfbox

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf, pdfbox

Want to create a signing workflow, a specific user creates some empty signatures and requests others to sign.

For the signature, I am using an external PKCS#1 raw signature API based, the problem in my understanding is that once somebody finishes the signature the hash value of the document is different form the original pdf, so the first signature becomes invalid.

Is there any way to sign with multiple signatures the same pdf and all signatures remain valid?

I am using PDFBOX library: pdfbox:2.0.20

Comment: No it's always incremental, i.e. the second signature signs the first signed one.

Comment: The first signature in the second signed pdf will be invalid or PDF reader understands the flow?

Comment: You might want to read [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) for backgrounds on PDF signatures.

Comment: No they don't get invalid. And yes you should read that answer :-)

Comment: Thank you guys for the documentation and the answer, much appreciated